Attendance Calculation based on date time selection


$(document).ready(function() {
    let rowCounter = 1;
    let totalTimeTaken = 0;

    // Function to calculate time difference
    function calculateTimeDifference(start, end) {
        const startDate = new Date(start);
        const endDate = new Date(end);

        const diffInMilliseconds = Math.abs(endDate - startDate);
        const days = Math.floor(diffInMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const hours = Math.floor((diffInMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        const minutes = Math.floor((diffInMilliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));

        return `${days} days ${hours} hrs ${minutes} mins`;
    }

    // Function to calculate total time taken
    function calculateTotalTimeTaken(timeTakenArray) {
        let totalTimeTaken = 0;

        timeTakenArray.forEach(timeTaken => {
            totalTimeTaken += timeTaken;
        });

        return totalTimeTaken;
    }

    // Function to create a new row
    function createNewRow() {
        if (rowCounter > 1) {
            $('input[name="start_time[]"]:last').attr('readonly', true);
            $('.delete-row:last').show();
        }

        const rowHtml = `<tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea name="description[]" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="start_time[]" class="form-control start_time" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="end_time[]" class="form-control end_time" required>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="time_taken[]" class="form-control time_taken" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="total_time_taken[]" class="form-control total_time_taken" readonly>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <i class="fas fa-trash delete-row"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        `;

        $('#myForm table tbody').append(rowHtml);
        rowCounter++;
    }

    // Function to remove the last row
    function removeLastRow() {
        if (rowCounter > 1) {
            $('table tbody tr:last-child').remove();
            rowCounter--;
        }
    }

    // Event listener for adding a new row
    $('#addRow').click(function() {
        createNewRow();
    });

    // Event listener for removing the last row
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-row', function() {
        removeLastRow();
    });

    // Event listener for datetime input
    $(document).on('change', '.start_time, .end_time', function() {
        const row = $(this).closest('tr');
        const startTime = row.find('.start_time').val();
        const endTime = row.find('.end_time').val();

        if (endTime < startTime) {
            row.find('.end_time').addClass('is-invalid');
            row.find('.start_time').addClass('is-invalid');
            $('.error-message').text('End time cannot be less than start time.');
        } else {
            row.find('.end_time').removeClass('is-invalid');
            row.find('.start_time').removeClass('is-invalid');
            $('.error-message').text('');

            const timeTaken = calculateTimeDifference(startTime, endTime);
            row.find('.time_taken').val(timeTaken);

            const timeTakenArray = $('input[name="time_taken[]"]').map(function() {
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            let currentRowTotalTimeTaken = calculateTotalTimeTaken(timeTakenArray);

            if (rowCounter > 1) {
                currentRowTotalTimeTaken += timeTaken;
            } else {
                currentRowTotalTimeTaken = timeTaken;
            }

            row.find('.total_time_taken').val(currentRowTotalTimeTaken);
            totalTimeTaken = currentRowTotalTimeTaken;
        }
    });

    // Event listener for form submission
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($('.is-invalid').length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'submit.php',
            method: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                alert('Data submitted successfully!');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
                alert('Error occurred while submitting data.');
            }
        });
    });

    // Show/hide buttons
    $('#addRow').click(function() {
        $('#validate').show();
    });

    $('button[type="button"]').click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') === 'validate') {
            $('#submit').show();
            $(this).hide();
        }

        if ($(this).attr('id') === 'submit') {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
.form-control {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.table thead th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.table tbody td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.table tbody tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.table tbody tr td:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}

.table tbody tr td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

.delete-row {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.error-message {
    color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic Table</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="text-center mb-5">Dynamic Table</h1>
        <form id="myForm">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Start Time</th>
                        <th>End Time</th>
                        <th>Time Taken</th>
                        <th>Total Time Taken</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="description[]" class="form-control">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="datetime-local" name="start_time[]" class="form-control start_time" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="datetime-local" name="end_time[]" class="form-control end_time" required>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="time_taken[]" class="form-control time_taken" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="total_time_taken[]" class="form-control total_time_taken" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <i class="fas fa-trash delete-row" style="display: none;"></i>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addRow">Add Row</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="validate" style="display: none;">Validate</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" style="display: none;">Submit</button>
            <p class="error-message"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



I need the value as below,



Time Taken
Total Time Taken




01 days 16 hrs 32 mins
1 days 16 hrs 32 mins


00 days 00 hrs 08 mins
1 days 16 hrs 40 mins



The total time taken should be the sum of all time taken up to the current row. However, when I run the code, the total time taken just add the text values like below
I tried changing the type of input from text to date-time with no luck.
Secondly I would like to validate if the end time of the first/previous row is equal to the start time of the current row if not to throw an error.
I'm not able to retrieve the live value of the fields since js is run when the documents is loaded.

Please be warned that your INSERT query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Please take the [tour] and read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title is not much more than tag salad.

@HereticMonkey I'm new to this site and I'm don't know much about it

That's why you are encouraged to take the [tour]

Yep, which is why I linked to places where you can learn about it. In order to ask a question, though, you presumably had to go through a wizard which advised you on many of the same things....

@HereticMonkey I've modified the question with working snippet.
